# Pluralization of nouns left out with conjunction

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

Can a repeated noun be left out in a conjunction? The particular example I am thinking of is a sentence that starts:

> Element A and element B....

Which I would shorten as:

> Element A and B...

I know I can do this with a definite article or a normal modifier, but if you can't leave out the noun, it should actually be:

> Elements A and B...

Which is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A search in [CocA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) suggests that they are both used among journalists and authors and therefore both are considered correct. It appears that the plural version is more commonly used though.

[image: Coca result]

Comment: Note that where it appears to be singular, the noun is attributive (used as an adjective): "class A and B schools"; "influenza A and B cultures"; "class A and B licenses". The main noun is always plural.

Comment: That's a single, spoken, example (from PBS Newshour). Speech is less careful than writing.

Comment: I resolved to use plural then, since it seems to fit in with general usage.